# Multiple condition in for loop

Tags: c++, c

During a code review today, I came across a loop that looked like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<some_value && !found ; ++i)
{
  if(some logic)
    {
    do_stuff();
    found=true;
    } 
}
```

I normally code things of this nature like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<some_value; ++i)
{
  if(some logic)
    {
    do_stuff();    
    break;
    } 
}
```

I have been programming for years and never until today seen more than one condition in a `for` loop. I understand it's perfectly valid code, as the `&&` simply gets evaluated and a result returned, I had simply never thought of using multiple conditions **inside** the for statement instead of the body.

I haven't seen this until today, and therefore must assume it's not very common.

**Are there any pitfalls to be aware of when using multiple conditions in a for loop check?**

Comment: *"If this question doesn't fit on StackOverflow, please help me adjust it so it does, or move it to the proper forum."* I think SO isn't a *forum*, but [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more appropriate for this question, see [Code Review: What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @DyP Possible... I don't know. I'm trying to ask about the C/C++ languages themselves, not only style. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: In a simple loop like this, an explicit break is obviously easier to follow (in my opinion; others might hold wrong opinions). If there are nested loops, it's less clear-cut: you can't break out of the outer one from the inner one, so your options are a flag, a `goto`, or refactoring the inner loop into a separate function.

Comment: for(unsigned i = 0, n = some_size; i < max_size && min_size < n; ++i. --n) may be clean code !

Comment: @DyP Code Review doesn't look like they want this type of question: "What is the best practice regarding X?" is off topic there.

Comment: And there are certainly cases where multiple conditions are warranted. Consider iterating over two ranges, stopping when you reach the end of the shorter one: `i != a.end() && j != b.end()`

Comment: @kmort OTOH, *it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?"*. Why don't you ask them, or just post your question there?

Comment: This is basically [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *"extremists"* that see `break` and `continue` as another word for the [*"accursed"* `goto`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful). Many Pascal/Delphi programmers are amongst this faction.

It is up to your coding convention if you should use such flags. I guess if you code like that in a non-academic context, that people won't take you serious. Be aware!

Of course you need such flags if you want to drop out of an outer loop, if your language does not know labeled loops. For example JavaScript and Java (and I think PHP too) support labeled loops.

I don't think that there are any pitfalls. If your compiler isn't way too dumb, it will determine the usage if such flags, and rewrite to code to use proper jumps.

There is (at least) one advantage of using such flags: It will be easier to prove the correctness of the code, e.g. using [Hoare calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic).

Answer (score 1):

Hi to answer your question, I am a college senior in the computer science program. I personally prefer to have multiple constraints inside the for loop. I feel it helps with debugging and keeping errors low. Is it more resource dependent? I'm not so sure.